# MySQL query (condition)

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve one thing though I'm not sure if it's possible.
So let's say I have a table with few columns, but only two of them are of interest to me right now. Example of table:

```
Column 1  | Column 2 
blabla    | blablahhhhh
wor154    | blablahhhhh
word123   | word12435564
something | some4565
```

What I want to achieve, is to select all fields where first 5 or more symbols of value of Column 2 don't match with first 5 or more symbols of value of Column 1. So I don't want to select rows where 5 or more symbols of value of Column 1 match 5 or more symbols of value of Column 2. In example, query should return only 2nd and 4th rows
So, is it possible and if it's, how it can be achieved. Thank you.

Comment: You want to return them or not return them?  Rows 2 & 4 above both match that condition, but you say you want the ones that don't match.

Comment: Is it certain that both fields will have length at least 5 characters?  If not, how would your selection criterion apply when one or both fields have fewer characters (shorter strings)?

Comment: hardmath, even if it's not certain and and Col1=a and Col2=b, query below will select it, if Col1=a and Col2=a it won't so it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with a [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 5) <> SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 5);
```

Comment: Even easier with `LEFT(Col1, 5)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use something similar to this:

```
select *
from table1
where substring(column1, 1, 5) != substring(column2, 1, 5)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a030b/3)

Comment: There is no '!=' in MySQL, as I remember. Use <> instead.